# Unexpected Warning using Enum Functional API - PyCharm Bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, pycharm

Using the Functional API example given in documentation 8.13.12. I get the following Warning (using python 3.6). The code does work in the console but I'd rather not have warnings upon my code inspection. What am I doing wrong? And how can I get rid of the warning?

```
from enum import Enum
Animal = Enum('Animal', 'ANT BEE CAT DOG')
```

> Unexpected argument(s) Possible callees: Enum.**new**(cls: Enum, value) object(self: object) less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info: Reports discrepancies between declared parameters and actual arguments, as well as incorrect arguments (e.g. duplicate named arguments) and incorrect argument order. Decorators are analyzed, too

Comment: Can not reproduce.  Are you sure this isn't just some stupid PyCharm garbage?  Python itself doesn't try to do a static inspection like that.

Comment: Yes I'm using PyCharm, but I don't use another editor. Anyway, I wasn't expecting the error and it's both frustrating and confusing. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Using latest PyCharm Community 2018.3.2.

Comment: This is a PyCharm issue.  Please file a bug with them to include proper `Enum` support.

Comment: Just found this in jetbrains bugtacker, some users claim the bug has been going since late 2015.... :(  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17877

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bug was fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17877) in PyCharm 2020.1.