# Enforce `Unresolved attribute reference` when referencing non-existing Python enums.Enum

Tags: python, enums, pycharm

I am just disappointed with the behavior of Enum vs standard object-based class, that I don't get in my IDE warning about `Unresolved attribute reference`, maybe I am not aware of some OO nuance which will allow making this happen?

```py
class Animal(Enum):
    ant = 1
    bee = 2
    cat = 3
    dog = 4
```

writing `Animal.tiger` should imply a warning about `Unresolved attribute reference`.

How to get there?

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: It is not matter of IDE. My pycharm does it perfectly fine for standard python class over object

Comment: of course it is a matter of IDE, this is a *feature of the IDE* not of the language itself. You should tag this with pycharm.

Comment: So, I installed PyCharm and can confirm that no warning is generated. This seems like a PyCharm bug, nothing really to do with Python enums *per se* or OOP generally, since `Animal.tiger` will give you the runtime error you'd expect. You may want to post an issue to the official tracker, which I believe is here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Comment: Static inspection of `enum` in pycharm has some problems, here's another such example straight out of the docs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030579/unexpected-warning-using-enum-functional-api-pycharm-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in PyCharm 2022.1, the `Unresolved attribute reference` warning is now correctly shown by the IDE's linter.

[image: linter warning]