# PyCharm type warnings - Iterable vs ValuesView/KeysView/ItemsView

Tags: python, pycharm, warnings

Lately in PyCharm (I don't know which version started it, I'm currently running 2021.2.3 Pro), I'm getting warnings that don't make sense.

For example, this snippet:

```py
d = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
for v in d.values():
    print(v)
```

Triggers the following warning:

> Expected type 'collections.Iterable', got 'ValuesView' instead

In the above snippet, replacing `values()` with `keys()` gives a similar warning.

BTW, the return value of `d.values()` is `dict_values` and not ValuesView:

```py
type(d.values())
<class 'dict_values'>
```

Why does PyCharm give me this warning, when this has always been the correct way to iterate over dictionary keys/values?

It might be a bug in PyCharm, but maybe I'm missing something.

---

**EDIT:** Even the sample code at https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views gets this warning, see screenshot.[image]

Comment: There's really not much you can do about PyCharm linter bugs. I've seen these bugs come and go over the years, here's one example from stdlib that [took some time to be fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030579) but since the bug you report in looping over a key/value view of a dict is an extremely common operation I'm guessing the next PyCharm version will ship a fix. The only possible conclusion is to know when your linter is wrong and ignore those bugs. In cases when the PyCharm linter is wrong you can double check using [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression of a known bug in the PyCharm 2021.2.3 linter, see [PY-41457](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41457) on the JetBrains bug tracker.

It doesn't happen for me using the immediately previous PyCharm 2021.2.2 Pro version.

The solution, for now, is to report the regression on the JetBrains bug tracker and wait for a fix. There's nothing wrong with your code.